# Matlab - JPEG Compression. Huffman Encoding

Tags: matlab, jpeg, huffman-code

I've been trying to implement a JPEG compression algorithm on Matlab.
The only part I'm having trouble implementing is the huffman encoding. I do understand the DCT into quantization and zig-zag'ing that 8x8 matrix. I also understand how does huffman encoding work, in general.
What I do not understand is, after I have an output bitstream and a dictionary that translates consecutive bits to their original form, what do I do with the output? How can I tell a computer to translate that output bitstream using the dictionary I created for it?
In addition, each 8x8 matrix will have its own output and dictionary. How can all these outputs be combined into one? Because at the end of the day, the result is supposed to be an image.
I might have misunderstood some of the steps, in which case my apologies for any confusion caused by this.
Any help would be extremely appriciated!

EDIT: I'm sorry, my question appearntly hasn't been clear enough. Say I use Matlabs built in huffman functions (huffmanenco and huffmandict), what am I supposed to do with the value the huffmanenco returns? 
The part of what to do with the output string of bits hasn't been clear to me as far as huffman encoding goes in other IDE's and programming languages aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices with the huffman coding.

1. Use a pre-canned huffman table.
2. Make two passes over the data where the first pass generates the huffman tables and the second pass encode.

You cannot have a different dictionary for each MCU.

You say you have the run length encoded values. You huffman encode those and write to the output stream.

EDIT:

You need to be sure that the matlab huffman endocoder is JPEG-compatible. There are different ways to huffman encode.

You need to write the bits from the encoder to the JPEG stream. This means you need a bit level I/O routine. PLUS you need to convert FF values in the compressed data into FF00 values in the JPEG stream.

I suggest getting a copy of

[http://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Image-File-Formats-JPEG/dp/0201604434/ref=pd_sim_14_1?ie=UTF8&dpID=41XJBED6RCL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR127%2C160_&refRID=1DYN5VCQQP0N88E64P5Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604434)

to show how the encoding is done.

Comment: First off, thanks for replying. My question regarding the encoding may seem really basic to those who already understand it. I edited it to clarify what I meant.