# I am trying to implement jpeg compression using FFT2 instead of DCT2 in Matlab and export binary files to be decoded

Tags: matlab, binary, fft, jpeg

As per the title, I am having more trouble trying to convert to binary file. Below are my steps.

**JPEG Compression Steps**

1. Convert RGB into 3 channels
2. For each channel (Y,Cb,Cr)

- (2.1) If channel is Cb or Cr

  - Downsample
- (2.2) Break channel into 8x8 non-overlapping blocks
- (2.3) For each block

  - (2.3.1) Apply 2D FFT

    - Output is a 8x8 frequency table
  - (2.3.2) Quantization

    - Element-wise divide by quantization table
    - Round to nearest whole number
    - The quantization table for Y is different from that of Cb and Cr
  - (2.3.4) ZigZag traversal through the coefficients

    - Maximize the effectiveness of run length encoder
    - Output is still a 8x8 frequency table but position is changed
  - (2.3.5) Run Length Encoding

    - Output is a cell with 2 matrix
    - Count matrix
    - Symbols matrix
  - (2.3.6) Huffman encoding

    - Encode count matrix
    - Encode symbols matrix

3. Somehow create a binary file format for export

**JPEG Decoder Steps**

- Read Binary file
- Decode huffman
- Reverse run length
- Reverse zigzag traversal
- Multiply by quantization table
- Inverse 2D FFT
- Reconstruct 8x8 Block

The specifics of the steps depends on the implementation of the Binary file format

**Binary file Format**

Information it should contain

- Quantization table (1 for Y and 1 for Cb and Cr)
- Huffman table/dictionary
- The actual image data

**Generating Huffman table**
[Matlab - JPEG Compression. Huffman Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379725/matlab-jpeg-compression-huffman-encoding)

1. Scan through all the blocks to generate a huffman table/dictionary
2. Encode all the blocks

I am new to matlab, I am unfamiliar with how to write binary files. How do I export the Huffman encoding in a binary file? I am working with the builtin matlab huffman functions.

From experimenting with the huffman function, I understand that the output is a cell array of matrices. The first column of the cell array is for symbols, the second column of the cell array is the code. The code is already in binary form but in Matlab it is just an array of integers. My main challenge is trying to write these codes into the binary file. I am not sure to write these code directly as binary values instead of being treated as decimals in matlab.

I would be happy to clarify my question if it is unclear. I would appreciate any help on this :)

Comment: Did you try typing `matlab write binary file` into your favorite search engine?

Comment: Yes, I know how to write binary files. But I am not sure how to write a something that is already in binary into a binary file. I am not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: [`bit2int`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/bit2int.html) will convert your bit listing to bytes, but you may have to cast your encoded values to `uint8` first.

Comment: From the Mathworks docs: `fwrite(fileID,A)` writes the elements of array A as 8-bit unsigned integers to a binary file in column order. The binary file is indicated by the file identifier, `fileID`. Use `fopen` to open the file and obtain the `fileID` value. When you finish writing, close the file by calling `fclose(fileID)`.